# How does one transfer python code written in a windows laptop to a samsung android phone?

Tags: android, python, ftp, qpython

I created numerous python scripts on my pc laptop, and I want to run those scripts on my android phone. How can I do that? How can I move python scripts from my windows pc laptop, and use those python scripts on my samsung adroid phone?

I have downloaded qpython from the google playstore, but I still don't know how to get my pc python programs onto my phone. I heard some people talk about "ftp" but I don't even know what that means.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use TeamViewer to control your android phone from your PC. And copy and paste the code easily.
or
You can transfer your scripts on your phone memory in the qpython folder and open it using qpython for android.

Answer (score 0):

Send them to yourself via email, then download the scripts onto your phone and run them through qpython.
However you have to realize not all the modules on python work on qpython so your scripts may not work the same when you transfer them.